# Maintaining long number string in R, avoiding scientific notation and not deleting leading zeroes

Tags: r, csv

I am having an issue with R enforcing scientific notation and deleting my leading 0s. I have capture history over 24 intervals where an animal caught is marked 1, and 0 if not. I have this in excel .csv and .txt files.

I have tried loading into R via the .csv file then running:

```
with_options(c(scipen=999),(str_pad(data$capture.history,24, pad="0")))
```

This almost works but this adds an extra 0 in front of capture histories that don't need it and add a bunch of odd values in spots that aren't supposed to be there such as "010000009999999999934424" for some but not all of the histories.

I upload the .txt file using:

```
cjs <- read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE, sep="\t", strip.white=TRUE)
```

And pretty much the same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps have a look at the `colClasses=` argument, which allows you to **tell** `read.csv()` and friends how to treat each column, rather than letting them / forcing them to  guess:

```
cat("char1, char2, num1\n01000, 00000004000, 0004\n", file="eg.csv")

read.csv("eg.csv")
#   char1 char2 num1
# 1  1000  4000    4

read.csv("eg.csv", colClasses=c("character", "character", "numeric"))
# char1        char2 num1
#1 01000  00000004000    4
```

Comment: Hi Josh, 
Thank you so much, this worked really well!
Thank you!

Comment: @JustinHubbard Glad to help. The key piece is to recognize that though those capture history records are made up of digits, they aren't really numbers (and then of course to know how to communicate that to R). If this solves your problem, you can indicate that to others by clicking on the check mark just to the left of my answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell it solved my problem, I hit the check mark!
My model seems to run okay now even though the capture history aren't really numbers. Cheers!